# Django mail send_mail uses host IP instead of hostname returned by getfqdn

Tags: django

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/email/), django default backend uses smtplib.

I am using django email to send emails in the following manner:

```
email = EmailMessage(
    'Object',
    'body',
    my_from_addr,
    args.emails,
    [],
    reply_to=['my_from_addr'],
)
```

with the following configuration in settings.py :

```
EMAIL_HOST = "mail_server.lan"
EMAIL_PORT = 25
```

I need to set the helo/ehlo parameter to comply with the email server according to the sending server hostname. But django seems to be using the IP of the server instead of the hostname, until now my emails have been rejected with the error

```
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'args.emails': (450, b'4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [192.168.1.5]')}
```

The smtplib documentation declares [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/smtplib.html)

```
If specified, local_hostname is used as the FQDN of the local host in the HELO/EHLO command. Otherwise, the local hostname is found using socket.getfqdn().
```

And this actually returns the proper hostname:

```
python3 -c 'import socket; print(socket.getfqdn())'
my_proper_hostname.lan
```

Am I missing something? Why is django using the IP address instead of the real hostname?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the host in your `settings.py` file:

For example:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com' # specify email server address here
```

Comment: That would be the email server to contact to send the email, my problem comes from the client server, I can add my configuration to my post

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be ***misconfiguration on mail server `mail_server.lan`***. not in django.

`SMTPRecipientsRefused` error indicates errors encountered while sending emails to recipients - and this operation is performed by smtp mail server.

It received message from django (as there are no connection errors) and tried to send individual email for each recipient (to / cc) of that message. And sending one of them failed.

Mail server makes similar helo / ehlo negotiation with upstream servers.

**Does your mail server provides correct maildomain / hostname ?** (ip in error message suggests that mail server is sending ip, not its domain).

Then, many servers will also check PTR record for your ip - first, resolve provided mail domain name to get ip, then resolve this ip back - to get PTR record - to check that it matches mail domain. PTR record usually can be set with your internet provider / hoster.